# Get element from JavaScript object

Tags: javascript

I have an object like below I want to search/find element by based on "96f54547-767c-434b-bcb4-a239a36b1c56" and get an array ["x", "y"]. How to achieve this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var cList = {
    "96f54547-767c-434b-bcb4-a239a36b1c56": ["x","y"],
    "fd3f9224-9fa5-49f5-9eea-ffd0ff40fdb0": [null,"y"],
    "843ed981-979f-4639-be6d-93665e52246f": [null,"y"],
    "2208ca60-c0d1-4ee9-aaae-291bef9622fa": [null,"y"]
};     
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [bracket operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) to find the `Array`:

```
var values = cList["96f54547-767c-434b-bcb4-a239a36b1c56"];
```

Either hard-coded as above or with the key stored in another variable:

```
var guid = "96f54547-767c-434b-bcb4-a239a36b1c56";
var values = cList[guid];
```

Also, if you want to test whether the `Object` even has the key, you can use the [`in` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in):

```
if (!(guid in cList)) {
    throw new Error('Data does not include the expected GUID: ' + guid);
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised people aren't jumping down your throat about using `in` instead of `hasOwnProperty()`

Comment: @Ian It's a good suggestion, but I don't think one is absolute over the other. There are use cases where acknowledging the prototype chain is the desired effect. Plus, in this case, shouldn't have to worry too much about the difference with a plain `Object`. There's far more opposition to extending `Object.prototype`. :)

Comment: My point was just that I get heckled when I don't, and I think it's silly. Too many people think the only "safe" way to check for an object literal's property is with `hasOwnProperty`...because of Crockford, Resig, blah blah blah. It's just good to see someone else be okay not using it :)

Comment: It's not a bad idea to mention both versions and explain the differences though.

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this

```
 var value= cList["96f54547-767c-434b-bcb4-a239a36b1c56"]
```

Comment: Did _you_ try that first option before recommending it? (Stack Overflow's colour-based syntax highlighting should give you a hint as to why it won't work...)

Comment: Didn't tried with this code, but I have implemented it in my code some time ago

Comment: That first option is saying `cList.96f54547` _minus_ `767c` _minus_ `434b` _minus_ `bcb4` _minus_ `a239a36b1c56`. Note that the second option is the same as in the answer that was posted seventeen minutes before yours...

Comment: Thanks for giving me the direction